# Exclude directory when grepping with zsh globbing

Tags: linux, zsh, glob, oh-my-zsh

I have some file structure which contains projects with build folders at various depths. I'm trying to use zsh (extended) globbing to exclude files in build folders.

I tried using the following command and many other variants:

`grep "string" (^build/)#`

I'm reading this as "Any folder that doesn't match `build` 0 or more times."

However I'm still getting results from folders such as:

./ProjectA/build/.../file.mi

./ProjectB/package/build/.../file2.mi

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which versions of `zsh` and `grep` are you using and do you perchance use `grep` with the `-r` option? At least on my installations (`zsh` 5.0.6 and 5.2) `(^build/)#` will only expand to matching directories but not files as the pattern ends with an `/`. So `grep` should not find anything (and maybe even complain) without the recursive option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
grep string (^build/)#*(.)
```

#### Explanation:

- `^build`: anything not named `build`
- `^build/`: any *directory* not named build. It will not match any other file type
- `(^build/)#`: any directory path consisting out of elements that are not named `build`. Again, this will not match a path where the last element is not a directory
- `(^build/)#*`: Any path where all but the last element must not be named `build`. This will also list files. It also assumes that it would be ok, if the file itself were named `build`. If that is not the case you have to use `(^build/)#^build`
- `(^build/)#*(.)`: Same as before, but restricted to only match normal files by the glob qualifier `(.)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to involve the shell for that task; `grep` comes with its own file-globber. From [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

```
--exclude-dir=GLOB
      Skip  any  command-line directory with a name suffix that matches the pattern GLOB.  When searching recursively, skip any subdirectory whose
      base name matches GLOB.  Ignore any redundant trailing slashes in GLOB.
```

So something like this should get the job done for you:

```
grep -R "string" --exclude-dir='build'
```

That filter will leave out subdirectories called exactly "build"; if you want to filter out directories that **contain** the string "build" (such as "build2" or "test-build") then use globbing inside the exclusion pattern:

```
grep -R "string" --exclude-dir='*build*'
```

---

For completeness' sake, I also include here how to do the same thing with two popular `grep` alternatives that I'm more or less familiar with:

- [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher): `ag -G '^((?!build).)*$' string`
- [Ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep): `rg -g '!build'`

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. This will work in this case, but I'd like to be able to reproduce the same result strictly with zsh globbing so I can use it for more commands than just grep.

Answer (score 0):

Using the glob qualifier `e` did the trick for me, both for 'grep' and 'ls':

```
grep -s "string" **/*(e[' [[ ! `echo "$REPLY" | grep "build/" ` ]]'])
```